# Angular - Ngrx - Updates from multiple sources and component rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I've got the following issue and I do need some advice how to tackle this best.

On our application we do a have a **container component** as following:

### ArchiveAllComponent

```
export class ArchiveAllComponent implements OnInit {

  archiveAllViewModel$: Observable<ArchiveAllViewModel>

  constructor(
    private store: Store<ApplicationState>,
    private votingService: VotingService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to any changes in the category and voting entities
    this.archiveAllViewModel$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(selectCategoriesWithVoting),
      map((categories: Category[]) => mapToArchiveAllViewModel(categories))
    )

    // Load all categories
    this.votingService.getCategories().subscribe((categories: Category[]) => {
      this.store.dispatch(new LoadCategoryAction(categories));
    });

    // Load all votings
    this.votingService.getVotings().subscribe((votings: Voting[]) => {
      this.store.dispatch(new LoadVotingAction(votings));
    });
  }

}
```

Once this component is rendered, two HTTP GET requests are being executed to different API's.

For each of those request an **action** is **dispatched** to the **store**.

### Reducer

```
// Reducer function
export function entityReducer(currentState: Entities, action: EntityActionsUnion): Entities {
    switch (action.type) {   

        case EntityActionTypes.LOAD_CATEGORIES:
            return merge({}, currentState, {categories : action.categories});

        case EntityActionTypes.LOAD_VOTINGS:
            return merge({}, currentState, {votings : action.votings});

        default:
            return currentState;
    }
}
```

### Selectors

```
export function selectCategoryEntity(state: ApplicationState) {
    return state.entities.categories;
}

export function selectVotingEntity(state: ApplicationState) {
    return state.entities.votings;
}

export const selectCategoriesWithVoting = createSelector(
    selectCategoryEntity,
    selectVotingEntity,
    (categoryEntities: Category[], votingEntities: Voting[]) => {
        if (categoryEntities && categoryEntities.length > 0 && votingEntities && votingEntities.length > 0) {
            let categories = categoryEntities.slice();
            votingEntities.forEach(voting => {
                if (voting.categoryId) {
                    let category = categories.find(x => x.id == voting.categoryId);
                    if(!category.votings) 
                    {
                        category.votings = [];
                    }
                    category.votings.push(voting);
                }
            });

            return categories;
        }

        return [];
    }
);
```

The `archiveAllViewModel$` observable is then passed to some child components for rendering the HTMl accordingly.

This seemed to work on first glance and even if you do a refresh, the following is executed:

1. Page Refresh
2. `getCategories()` + Action / reducer is triggered
3. `getVotings()` + Action / reducer is triggered
4. `<archiveElement>` + first child element is correctly rendered
5. `<archiveElement>` + second child element is correctly rendered
6. `<archiveElement>` + third child element is correctly rendered

The problem starts to appear, as soon as I start to navigate away from the component and come back to the same route via client site routing.

```
<a routerLink="/someotherpage" routerLinkActive="active" mat-button>Other Page</a>
```

Returning to the same component:

```
<a routerLink="/archiveAll" routerLinkActive="active" mat-button>Archive</a>
```

Now compared to a full page refresh, everything is rendered twice:

1. Navigating away
2. Navigating back
3. `<archiveElement>`
4. `<archiveElement>`
5. `<archiveElement>`
6. `getCategories()` + Action / reducer is triggered
7. `<archiveElement>`
8. `<archiveElement>`
9. `<archiveElement>`
10. `getVotings()` + Action / reducer is triggered
11. `<archiveElement>`
12. `<archiveElement>`
13. `<archiveElement>`

As a result **each of the the child components now appears twice on the page**.

### Troubleshooting

The `createSelector` is now being executed for each http requests once because the predicate `categoryEntities && categoryEntities.length > 0 && votingEntities && votingEntities.length > 0` is now **no longer only valid for the second http request**.

### My question

- What are some best practises to solve issues like that?
- Are there any operators who can easily solve that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with Angular. After some further debugging I realised that the issue was within the selector function.

I've refactored it and now seems to work!

```
export const selectCategoriesWithVoting = createSelector(
    selectCategoryEntity,
    selectVotingEntity,
    (categoryEntities: Category[], votingEntities: Voting[]) => {
        if (categoryEntities && categoryEntities.length > 0 && votingEntities && votingEntities.length > 0) {
            let categories = categoryEntities.slice();       
            votingEntities.forEach(newVoting => {
                if (newVoting.categoryId) {
                    let category = categories.find(x => x.id == newVoting.categoryId);
                    if(!category.votings) 
                    {
                        category.votings = [];
                    }                 

                    let oldVotingIndex = category.votings.findIndex(x => x.id == newVoting.id);
                    if(oldVotingIndex != -1)
                    {
                        category.votings[oldVotingIndex] = newVoting;
                    } else {
                        category.votings.push(newVoting);
                    }
                }
            });

            return categories;
        }

        return [];
    }
);
```

Comment: You are mutating objects from the state within that selector, I would strongly suggest you to avoid that.

Comment: That's why i use the `merge()` function within the reducer to do a deep clone of the state. Let me know if I still miss something. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge

Comment: is he muting state? Because he is using .slice it will create a copy?

Comment: `slice()` will only do a shallow copy and thus preserve nested object references. That's why I started using `merge()` from the lodash library  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the subscription on `this.votingService.getCategories()` and `this.votingService.getVotings()` isn't getting destroyed. Meaning it will re-load every time a request is made.

To fix this you can destroy the subscription on `ngDestroy`, but rather then doing this I would suggest to take a look at [@ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects) to handle all your side effects (like for example http requests).

Comment: do you have any guesses why it only doubles the `child elements`, even though I navigate multiple times away and back? Nevertheless, I will take a look at `ngrx/effects`.

Comment: maybe because it's doubled in the state?

Comment: Im not sure what makes you think that. Asumming that `votingService.getCategories/getVotings` returns an observable created by the HttpClient API, then the issue that you describe wouldnt apply.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I'm not sure if this the case, it was more a question than an answer. The reason why I asked was because I don't see all the code to have an answer, and perhaps `merge` will append the items.